# Angular subscription to GraphQL mutation from Appsync Client

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-client, aws-appsync

I'm working on a chat app in Angular using GraphQL with Appsync in AWS. The workflow at the moment when creating a new chat is that a new chat is mocked up and sent to the server, on the server side a chat_id is generated for this chat which i need to retrieve and send it to my local store.

My idea is that i should be able to subscribe to the mutate function, or the observable query that i create when doing the mutation. However, i receive the error "observable.subscribe is not a function" when trying to subscribe. And its the same if i try to subscribe to the entire function (the client.mutate function).

This is my current code which is causing the issue:

```
this.appsync
      .hc()
      .then(client => {
        const observable: ObservableQuery = client.mutate({
          mutation: createChatRoom,
          variables: {
            input: {
              user_id: user.id,
              text: text,
            }
          },
          fetchPolicy: "no-cache"
        })
        observable.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
      })
```

I can also console log the observable and see that the values are stored in the __zone_symbol_value variable on the observable object. But i cannot retrieve these values, or subscribe to the observable.

Any ideas or hints of how to go forward with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding a .then() statement after the client.mutate had been ran. Solution code:

```
this.appsync
  .hc()
  .then(client => {
    const observable: ObservableQuery = client.mutate({
      mutation: createChatRoom,
      variables: {
        input: {
          user_id: user.id,
          text: text,
        }
      },
      fetchPolicy: "no-cache"
    }).then(data => {
          conversation.id = data.data.createChatRoom.chat_id;
  })
```

For some reason i have to call data.data which i'm not sure why. If anyone knows that feel free to answer. Otherwise it works great :).

Comment: Have you tried passing header to this ?